# Order of the link in the page with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a simple `LinkExtractor` rule for a given domain. Something like this: `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('domain\.com/.+/\d+', )), callback='parse_page'),`

What I would like and I can't figure out, it's to know on which position was the link in the page.

For example, if a given domain has 5 links on the page that match my rule I need to know from the top to the bottom their order in the HTML.

I found many questions about the order of the extraction, but nothing, or I misunderstood something, about the order of the link itself in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy uses lxml to for html parsing. `LinkExtractor` uses `root.iter()` to iterate through. [This line to be more exact.](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py#L37)

[Lxml's docs say:](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration)

> Elements provide a tree iterator for this purpose. It yields elements
>   in document order, i.e. in the order their tags would appear if you
>   serialised the tree to XML:

so for html source:

```
<root>
  <child>Child 1</child>
  <child>Child 2</child>
  <another>Child 3</another>
</root>
```

it would yield:

```
>>> for element in root.iter(tag=etree.Element):
...     print("%s - %s" % (element.tag, element.text))
root - None
child - Child 1
child - Child 2
another - Child 3
```

You can replicate the process using the examples provided in the lxml docs link posted above.